# ВозвращатьСЯ, но уходить

Tags: словообразование

Резко подумалось: возвратная частица "-ся" означает действие, направленное на самого себя. Но почему, если "возвращатьСЯ", то "уходить"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, какого ответа Вы ждете на Ваше "почему", но, возможно, Вас удовлетворит тот факт, что уходить - глагол не переходный, поэтому возвратной частицы при себе не допускает (без существенного изменения смысла).

Кстати, точной антонимичной парой к уходить будет "приходить" а совсем не "возвращаться".

А у возвратной частицы насчитывается от пяти до семи функций - по разным системам подсчета.

//-----------------

Поскольку автор не уточнил вопрос, не претендую на полноту и правильность даже после принятия модератором.

Comment: Ну хватит уже придираться к вопросу "почему"! Как могут люди, так вопросы и формулируют!

Comment: "Возвращаться"  тоже  точная  антонимическая  пара  к  "уходить"  -  это  обратное  действие.

Comment: Это частичный антоеним - и не по главному значению.

Fuchoin Kazuki 
>Ну хватит уже придираться к вопросу "почему"! Как могут люди, так вопросы и формулируют!  
  
Вы неправильно меня трактуете. Когда я "придираюсь", я так и пишу. Тут - я почти что извиняюсь, за недостаточное понимание.

Answer (score 5):

Возвращаться - возвращать себя, а ведь возвратить можно не только себя. У слова "уходить" проблем с многозначностью нет, поэтому возвратная частица и излишня.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим "изначальные" глаголы: "ходить" и "возвращать". Первый не имеет объекта, только субъект. Второй же имеет объект (я возвращаю кого/что?), как и его "первообразный" глагол "вращать" (я вращаю кого/что?).

Что в итоге? Глагол "уходить" не нуждается в возвратной частице, чтобы обозначать действие, направленное на себя, ибо он изначально направлен на себя (я хожу – действие мое, направлено на меня, выполняется мной по отношению ко мне же). Глагол "возвращаться" нуждается в такой частице, потому что изначально он направлен на какой-то объект (я возвращаю деньги, например). Я возвращаюсь – это буквально "я возвращаю себя".